# How to remove a directory in www folder

Tags: command-line, 12.10

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10

I have a folder inside `/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/myFolder` called `myFolder`. Inside `myFolder` there are subfolders. Now I cannot remove it via the GUI, and when using terminal it also does not work, perhaps because I'm doing it wrong. I said:

```
sudo rmdir /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/myFolder/*
```

and I also tried just `rm`, but it keeps telling me "directory not empty" and some other errors as well. How do I delete it then that folder with all its contents?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sudo rm -R /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/myFolder/*`

-R to recursively remove anything inside it (and deeper).

This also removes files (not just directories).

Comment: what about `sudo rm -rf ...`?

Comment: It is the same. The only difference is that -f flag means --force ignore nonexistent files, never prompt. No message will appear telling you that you are going to delete something.

Comment: @MiJyn the f is only to not ask for confirmation ;)

Comment: yeah, of course, but I don't like being at my terminal always asked for confirmation of file deletion (especially if there are many)

Comment: me too @MiJyn but on AU I always choose the safer option ;)

Answer (score 2):

Complementing the answer of Rinzwind, you can also do it through GUI. You probably didn't have permissions to remove it as a normal user. Then, you need to launch file explorer as root. You can launch GUI as root by two different ways:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> `gksu nautilus`
- Or, in a terminal, type `sudo nautilus`

In both ways, you can navigate to `myFolder` and delete it.

Comment: Also correct. Just do not use it for anything else... bad things can happen if you do :)

Comment: @Rinzwind: good advice `:)`